# how 'let' keyword is accessible inside chrome dev tool as strict mode is not enabled by default?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I have tried to declare a variable inside chrome dev tool console using let keyword and it didn't give me any error.
But I heard that let keyword is only available in 'strict mode' and in dev tool strict mode is disabled.

```
let name = 'john';
console.log(name);
```

Comment: `I heard that let keyword is only available in 'strict mode'` that's simply not the case

Comment: `let` works in sloppy mode just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstand:

The purpose of "use strict" is to indicate that the code should be executed in "strict mode". With strict mode, you can not, for example, use undeclared variables.

And `let` is new keyword from ES2015, it can be use without strict mode.